# Play large volume of videos offline with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video

I would like to play a new video everyday in my AngularJS application. At the moment, my videos are stocked as files in my application folder and played with html5 video player, which make my application really heavy. Also, I need those videos to be available offline. I am asking this question here to get some ideas about how to play those videos in another way: less heavy and even if I'm offline. Anyone ?

My basic code:

```
<video id="video_background" class="video_bg" preload="auto" autoplay="" muted="" loop="muted" name="Video Name" src="http://video-url.com"></video>
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: Did you try anything ? please show us your code .

Comment: Yes @NiharSarkar my videos are played thanks to html5 video player locally. But I'm not asking for some code, I am asking for ideas, and then I will make some searches about those ideas. My code is not really useful as the method I use at the moment is working

Comment: It would be better if u show us your code .

Comment: Well there it is...